# Python3 curses doesn't recognize curses.resizeterm()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-curses

I am running Python on a Fedora PC(redhat linux), and ran IDLE from the terminal via python3 -m idlelib.idle. However, attempting to run `curses.resizeterm(40,40)` results in the error

```
File "/home/quowlord/Documents/ASCIIengineALPHA_1.py", line 75, in <module>
curses.resize_term(40,40)
AttributeError: module 'curses' has no attribute 'resize_term'
```

(Other curses calls worked, including ones that affected the terminal, such as `curses.start_color()` and `curses.initscr()`.)

I don't know what to try next, as I already tried reinstalling python.

Comment: Maybe because you spelled it `resize_term`?

Comment: Or maybe because `curses` is not the standard library module but some other file that happens to be named `curses.py`?

Comment: How is it supposed to be spelled? According to the documentation resizeterm and resize_term both exist, and neither works in my case. Sorry for any confusion my wording may have caused.

Comment: The two names are indeed a bit confusing. I don't know what might be the problem.

Comment: Which version?  The Python 3.8 on my Linux system certainly has `resize_term`.

Comment: Python 3.9.2. Could it be that my terminal doesn't support resizing?

Comment: Strangely enough, it doesn't crash on my laptop (also running fedora 33), but the terminal doesn't resize either.